# tailwin css doesn't upload correctly

Tags: css, reactjs, graphql, tailwind-css

I am working with tailwindcss, the css is not loaded immediately, it takes about 2 seconds. I hav this problem with all pages. I install tailwind by cdn
I add some pictures :before loaded css and with the css loaded 
How can I solve it? Thanks

[image: without css]

[image: with css]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html is rendered before the CSS file is loaded via CDN. Use `npm install tailwindcss` to install the package in your node modules. This is should solve the problem and is the preferable route if you want to go into production with this app.